# WakefulBroadcastReceiver onReceive method's context

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have the following lines of code for my broadcast receiver :

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Where does the context come from in this case? Why I'm asking is that my application crashed once in onPostExecute() of an async task, where I am actually calling getActivity.finish() and starting a new activity. Does the context come from the activity/fragment I am currently in when I receive the notification? If so, could it be I received notification exactly after I called finish on the activity and that's why I received a NPE on context?

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Checkin checkin) {
                        super.onPostExecute(checkin);
                            Activity activity = getActivity();
                            if (activity != null) {
                                activity.finish();
                            }

                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainDrawer.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
                        }
                    }

                }.execute();
```

This is the error I got when the app crashed :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

When checking the trace, it was in the callback of an async task I mentioned above, but the only place I call getPackageName() is the one in the code that I showed.

For future reference, I will make sure the context is not null before executing those lines on code in order to prevent the app from crashing but I am really curious about this at the moment.

Comment: "Where does the context come from in this case?" -- that is undocumented and any particular implementation should not be relied upon. "Does the context come from the activity/fragment I am currently in when I receive the notification?" -- no, because you are not necessarily in any activity when the GCM message arrives. Whether `onReceive()` is passed some temporary `Context`, the `Application` singleton, or something else, I cannot say.

Comment: In your problem description you mention `getActivity.finish()` did you mean `getActivity().finish()`, where `getActivity()` is the Fragment method?  Is so, possibly your AsyncTask is finishing when the fragment is no longer attached to an activity.

Comment: Need to move `startActivity()` inside the check for not null.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Thanks for the insight, what would be the explanation for this crash in that case? Or what would be an alternative for the implementation I follow so I won't rely on the context?

Comment: "what would be the explanation for this crash in that case?" -- no clue. Usually, I see that error when somebody tries using a component (e.g., an `Activity`) from a data member initializer. If this indeed is coming from your `onReceive()` method shown above, you are not doing that. "Or what would be an alternative for the implementation I follow so I won't rely on the context?" -- create your `ComponentName` via `new ComponentName(context, GcmIntentService.class)`.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I just got a new crash and I assume it is because of the null context: 

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.enloop.friendaccept flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.enloop.ui.fragments.drawer.profile.ProfileFragment$6@41d9c020`

Answer (score 0):

On Lollipop, the error message you posted occurs when an attempt is made to create an Intent with a null context, such as this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(null, MainActivity.class);
```

In your `onPostExecute()` method, move the call to `startActivity()` inside the check for activity not null.

Comment: sure, but in this case, if the context will be null when creating the intent, I will stay in that activity and not move forward

Comment: This is a symptom of a larger design problem.  You shouldn't be running the AsyncTask in a fragment that might not be attached to the activity when the task finishes.

Comment: That's also correct, but this is not where my problem comes from :) Problem comes from as CommonsWare explained